# How to set path as DataSource property name in DataSource object in Angular - EJ2 Tree view

Tags: angular, tree, treeview

Here I am setting Angular - EJ2 Tree view. I have to add 'path' as  DataSource property name which should be listed in nodeData of tree nodes.
Here is my code

```
 getArticleFolderTree(art_data) {
    this.articleviewservice
      .postArticleData(this._global.APIUrl + "get-article-folder", art_data)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.folder_nodes = {
            dataSource: response.file_list,
            id: 'id',
            parentID: 'pid',
            path: 'path',
            text: 'name',
            hasChildren: 'hasChild',
            child: 'children',
            iconCss: 'icon'
        };
      });
  }
```

```html
<ejs-treeview #foldertree *ngIf="view_folder_list"
              [fields]='folder_nodes' (nodeSelected)='clickMe($event)'>
</ejs-treeview>
```

```ts
public clickMe(args: any): void {
    console.log(args);  // here I need path from args.nodeData.path .
 }
```

Some of the properties are not listed in nodeData. I want to get the path from nodeData.